# Calculating a quaternion from two combined angles

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I'm creating a script that rotates a THREE.js camera arround based on a mobile phones gyroscope input. It's currently working pretty well, except that every time I rotate my phone over a quadrant, the camera will turn 180 degrees instead of continuing as intended. This is the code that I currently use:

```
private onDeviceOrientation = ( event ) => {

  if( event.alpha !== null && event.beta !== null && event.gamma !== null ) {

    let rotation = [
      event.beta,
      event.alpha,
      event.gamma
    ],

    this.orientation = new THREE.Vector3(rotation[0], rotation[1], rotation[2]);
    this.viewer.navigation.setTarget(this.calcPosition());
  }
};

private calcPosition = () => {

    const camPosition = this.viewer.navigation.getPosition(),
          radians = Math.PI / 180,
          aAngle = radians * - this.orientation.y,
          bAngle = radians * + this.orientation.z,
          distance = this.calcDistance();

    let medianX = Math.cos(bAngle) * Math.sin(aAngle);
    let medianY = Math.cos(bAngle) * Math.cos(aAngle);

    let nX = camPosition.x + (medianX * distance),
        nY = camPosition.y + (medianY * distance),
        nZ = camPosition.z + Math.sin(bAngle) * distance;
    return new THREE.Vector3(nX, nY, nZ);
};

window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', this.onDeviceOrientation, false);
```

Soafter doing some research I found that I need to use a Quaternion prevent the switchen when going into a new quadrant. I have no experience with Quaternions, so I was wondering what the best way would be to combine the two Vector3's in the code above into a singel Quaternion.

[Edit]

I calculate the distance using this method:

```
private calcDistance = (): number => {
    const camPosition = this.viewer.navigation.getPosition();
    const curTarget = this.viewer.navigation.getTarget();
    let nX = camPosition.x - curTarget.x,
        nY = camPosition.y - curTarget.y,
        nZ = camPosition.z - curTarget.z;
    return Math.sqrt((nX * nX) + (nY * nY) + (nZ * nZ));from squared averages
};
```

And I follow the [MDN conventions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) when working with the gyroscope.

[Edit #2]
Turns out I had my angle all wrong, I managed to fix it by calculating the final position like this:

```
let nX = camPosition.x - (Math.cos(zAngle) * Math.sin(yAngle)) * distance,
    nY = camPosition.y + (Math.cos(zAngle) * Math.cos(yAngle)) * distance,
    nZ = camPosition.z - (Math.cos(xAngle) * Math.sin(zAngle)) * distance;
```

Comment: How is the `orientation` property defined?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, but the orientation is a Vector3 which gets set in a callback of the `deviceorientation` event

Comment: There are [lots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) of [ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) to represent a 3-D orientation as a vector.  Can you be specific about the definition of `orientation`?  You are only using two of the three components in your calculations, so I suspect that the answer to this question will involve examining the third component as well; without this information I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Currently `orientation` is a Vector3 directly taken from the device gyroscope and will contain the axis angles in degrees, where y is the vertical axis and z the horizontal. The z axis is the roll in this case. As I want to use this to control the camera, I only want to calculate the horizontal and vertical rotations of the gyroscope to prevent camera rolling.

Comment: Do you have a link to the spec for the gyroscope angle conventions as well as the `distance` calculation?  I agree that in general you don't care about the roll, but when the pitch is near ±90°, the yaw and roll axes line up, and there is probably a discontinuity in both of them.  Still, I wouldn't think this would be an issue with calculating the location of the position unless the `distance` you calculate should go negative.

Comment: Hi I updated the question. Hopefully that helps

Comment: You say you're using the MDN conventions but you have properties of `orientation` named `y` and `z`.  Where are you assigning them?  Also, and I might be completely misreading this, what's the difference between the position returned by `this.viewer.navigation.getTarget()` and the one you're trying to calculate with `calcPosition()`?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of example code, but I also added the method that gets called when the device orientation changes. The position that I would like to calculate is the position based on the angle of the device orientation. I am using a framework with a custom camera controller with which I can only change either the camera position or the target it is looking at (both are Vector3's). So this way I am trying to reposition the camera's target to simulate the device movement. I use the getTarget() method here to fetch the current position of the target, on which I want to apply the device angles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the closest I can give you to an answer:

First of all, you don't need a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).  (If you really find yourself needing to convert between [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and quaternions, it is [possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) as long as you have all the axis conventions down pat.)  The Euler angle orientation information you obtain from the device is sufficient to represent any rotation without ambiguity; if you were calculating *angular velocities*, I'd agree that you want to avoid Euler angles since there are some orientations in which the rates of change of the Euler angles go to infinity.  But you're not, so you don't need it.

I'm going to try to summarize the underlying problem you're trying to solve, and then tell you why it might not be solvable.

---

You are given the full orientation of the device with a camera, as yaw, pitch, and roll.  Assuming yaw is like panning the camera horizontally, and pitch is like tilting the camera vertically, then roll is a degree of freedom that doesn't change affect direction the camera is pointing, but it does affect the orientation of the images the camera sees.  So you are given three coordinates, where two have to do with the direction the camera is pointing, and one does not.

You are trying to output this information to the camera controller but you are only allowed to specify the target location, which is the point in space that the camera is looking.  This is to be specified via three Cartesian coordinates, which you can calculate from the direction the camera is pointing (2 degrees of freedom) and the distance to the target object (one degree of freedom).

So you have three inputs and three outputs, but only two of those have anything to do with each other.  *The target location has no way to represent the roll direction of the camera, and the orientation of the camera has no way to represent the distance to some target object*.

Since you don't have a real target object, you can just pick an arbitrary fixed distance (1, for example) and use it.  You certainly don't have anything from which to calculate it... if I follow your code, you are defining distance in terms of the target location, which is itself defined in terms of the distance from the previous step.  This is extra work for no benefit at best (the distance drifts around some initial value), and numerically unstable at worst (the distance drifts toward zero and you lose precision or get infinities).  Just use a fixed value for distance and make it simple.

So now you probably have a system that points a camera in a direction, but you cannot tell it what the roll angle is.  That means your camera controller is apparently just going to choose it for you based on the yaw and pitch angles.  Let's say it always picks zero degrees (that would be the least crazy thing it could do).  This will cause discontinuities when the roll angle and yaw angle line up (when the pitch is at ±90°): Imagine pointing a physical camera at the northern horizon and yawing around westward, past the western horizon, and settling on the southern horizon.  The whole time, the roll angle of the camera is 0°, so there's no problem.  But now imagine pointing it at the northern horizon, and *pitching upward*, past the [zenith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenith), and continuing to pitch backward until you are facing the southern horizon.  Now the camera is *upside down*; the roll angle is 180°.  But if the camera controller doesn't change the roll angle from 0°, then it will do a nonphysical "flip" right when you pass the zenith.  The problem is that there really is no way to synthesize a roll angle based purely on position and not have this happen.  We've just demonstrated that there are two ways to move your camera from pointing north to pointing south, where the roll angle is completely different at the end.

So you're stuck, I guess.  Well, maybe not. Can you rotate the *image* from the camera based on the roll angle of the device orientation?  That is, add the roll back into the displayed image?  If so, you may have a solution.  Let's say the roll angle of the camera controller is always at zero.  Then you just rotate the image by the desired roll angle (something derived from `beta` I guess?) and you're done.  If the camera controller has some other convention for choosing the roll angle, you will need to figure that out, undo it, and add the roll angle back on.

Without the actual system in front of me I probably can't help you debug your way to a solution.  So I think this is where my journey with this question must end.  Good luck!

---

Summary:

- You don't need a quaternion
- Pick a fixed distance to your simulated target
- Add the roll angle by rotating the image before displaying it
- Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but turns out I had my axis all wrong. I'll add my solution to my answer :)